# Is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, imputation, r-mice

I'm tring tu use ggmice with ggplot2 but, when I try give me back this error.

I saw some explanations here but none solved my problem.

```
    ggmice(m.out, ggplot2::aes(.imp, Pixel_Deforested)) +
    geom_point()
 
 Error: 'as_label' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2'
```

Comment: Try with updating your `ggplot2` version. I'm using `3.4.0` and in this version `as_label` is exported.

Comment: You can [see here](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aamices%2Fggmice%20%20as_label&type=code) that this package does indeed call `ggplot2::as_label`. You can also see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4fea51b1eb2cdacebeacf425627dcbc1d61a5d3e/NAMESPACE#L296) that `as_label` _is_ exported from the latest version of ggplot2. My guess is that you are using an older version of ggplot. Try `install.packages("ggplot2")` to update.

Comment: Allan or stefan - post as an answer.

Comment: @Allan Cameron I think you are right my ggplot2 version is ggplot2_3.3.2, but I couldn't update it, I believe it's because of my version of R (R version 3.6.1). I'm going to update the r version and update ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

`ggmice` developer here! If the problem persists after updating `R`/`ggplot2`, please post an issue on Github, then I'll look into it! https://github.com/amices/ggmice/issues